# Solve $2x - |x+1| < 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Solve the equation $2x - |x+1| < 4$.

I start with splitting up into $a$ and $b$.

a) $x>-1$ leads to $x<5$

b) $x<-1$ leads to $x<1$.

Answer: $x<5$. Tha's not correct. Why? And what is the correct solution?

Answer (score 2):

If $x > -1$, then

$$4 > 2x - |x + 1| = 2x - (x + 1) = x - 1$$

implies that $x < 5$.

---

If $x < -1$, then

$$4 > 2x - |x + 1| = 2x + (x + 1) = 3x + 1$$

implies that $x < 1$.

So whenever $x < -1$, this condition obviously holds. If $x > -1$, then it's also necessary that $x < 5$; hence, the solution is $x < 5$.

Comment: Thank you. Of course, just logic and the end.

Answer (score 1):

Divide your answer in two:

- When $x>-1$
- When $x<-1$

When $x>0$ your equation is $2x-x-1<4$ which comes to $x<5$.

When $x<0$ your equation is $2x-(-x-1)<4$ which comes to $x<1$

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases, as you have mentioned:

$x\ge-1 \Rightarrow x< 5$, so a subset of solutions is $x\in[-1,+\infty)\cap(-\infty,5) = [-1,5)$; and

$x<-1 \Rightarrow x< 1$, so a subset of solutions is $x\in(-\infty,-1)\cap(-\infty,1) = (-\infty,-1)$.

And by simplifying, $x<5$ is the solution.